# Slow new laptop with fresh Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: partitioning

My Ubuntu laptop had a lot of problems during OS installation, and now it's "working" fine besides the fact that it is horribly slow at everything (boot, any action taken after booting, etc.). We're speaking 5+ seconds for any action with no apparent freezing.

I was wondering if the partition table may be at cause, because it looks unusual. Here is the output of 'sudo parted --list':

```
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32        EFT System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   1000GB  1000GB  ext4
```

I can output more terminal commands outputs if necessary.

EDIT: I wiped the hard-drive and re-installed the OS as the laptop is new anyway, so there was no relevant data or software on it I wanted to save. The problem persists, but is somehow worsAs requested, additional information about my laptop.

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS 64-bit 
Kernel : Linux 5.0.0-29-generic
Processor: Intel Core i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20 GHz x 12
GNOME 3.28.2
```

I can boot using nomodeset and it runs reasonably fast, but still a bit slower than expected (and of course this is for debugging, I don't want to always boot like that...). Without nomodeset it's horribly slow until it eventually freezes (I managed to avoid freezing before, I don't know why it happens again now).

Output of systemd-analyze blame :

```
9.680s dev-sda2.device
6.567s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
4.788s snapd.service
3.237s udisks2.service
2.937s dev-loop3.device
2.904s dev-loop4.device
2.903s dev-loop6.device
2.903s dev-loop1.device
2.903s dev-loop5.device
2.850s plymouth-quit-wait.service
2.825s dev-loop7.device
2.820s ModemManager.service
2.500s accounts-daemon.service
2.170s networkd-dispatcher.service
2.148s NetworkManager.service
1.924s dev-loop2.device
1.860s dev-loop0.device
1.826s systemd-journal-flush.service
1.779s fwupd.service
1.639s apport.service
1.636s networking.service
1.600s alsa-restore.service
1.600s bluetooth.service
1.599s pppd-dns.service
1.597s thermald.service
1.596s avahi-daemon.service
1.590s rsyslog.service
```

EDIT: @doug, here

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics: Card-1: Intel Device 3e9b
          Card-2: NVIDIA GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
          Display Server: X11 (X.Org 1.20.4)
          drivers: fbdev (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
          Resolution: 800x600@75.00hz
          OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits)
          version: 3.3 Mesa 19.0.2
```

I realize it may not help much since it was run in nomodeset. It's the only way I can access terminal. Like I said in the other comment, I can't access a terminal without freezing my computer, even before login with Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Comment: Have you checked the SMART status, ie. health of your drive. Some drives with long warranties become slow but keep operating to avoid warranty claims (which can be evidenced by viewing SMART data).  ie. `smartctl`, `gnome-disks`, `kde partition manager` etc.

Comment: The laptop is new, so I didn't think the laptop itself could be the problem. Unless I bought a problematic laptop.

Comment: I edited the question title since it is not the problem anymore and I added some details @Rinzwind

Comment: At login screen, Ctrl+Alt+F1 causes a freeze.

Comment: Install inxi and run `inxi -G` , post result

Comment: @doug: done, but not sure it helps.

Comment: @doug I updated my post with inxi output, but I don't think it'll help much since I can only run it in nomodeset... I am trying to have a look at my hard drive using smartctl.

Comment: you need to install the nvidia driver (I have same GPU here). I'd suggest using the 435 driver from this ppa - https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa  After adding ppa install with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435` or use synaptic to install. Also make sure you're not logging into a wayland session. Additionally make sure to not be using nomodeset boot option, can be checked with `cat /proc/cmdline`

Comment: You may want to on the  reboot after installing driver go to the advanced options in grub screen , press e and remove nomodeset if it's on the boot option line. If it is then you'll need to edit `/etc/default/grub` to remove it, then `sudo update-grub` to make the removal permanent

Comment: @doug I was manually adding nomodeset after each boot where I wanted to do it, I didn't touch grub. I guess I can boot in nomodeset, install the driver and try again.

Comment: @doug : for my personal culture: you think it might be trying to login with the NVIDIA graphic card without the driver and just freeze there?

Comment: Not sure, I'd think it should boot up using nouveau but, at least in my case it wouldn't. I have a similar laptop (HP Omen) where it's an nvidia GPU only, no optimus. So the only way to use the laptop properly was to install and use the nvidia driver.

Comment: Actually had a bug report on that, no attention - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1822482

Comment: Alright, turns out my fresh OS install paid off, because last time I also installed NVIDIA drivers and I had a huge problem. This time I thought I would get better results even before installing driver (i.e. running with nouveau driver) but I couldn't even get to a first login. Your solution (installing the nvidia driver while in nomodeset and rebooting normally, without nomodeset) solved my problem, but after a OS install where I *completely wiped the disk clean* (just in case someone uses this solution...)

Answer (score 4):

> I was wondering if the partition table may be at cause,

No.

> because it looks unusual.

How so? You have 2 partitions, one is the EFI partition formatted as FAT and 1 is your useable partition (rounded up it is 1000Gb) formatted as EXT.

A hard disk comes in 2 groups: slow hdd and quick ssd. hdd comes largely in 2 groups too 5400 rpm and 7200 rpm. The 5400 rpm is slow as hell nowadays so wait time are to be expected. If you use an ssd I would worry about the health of the disk.

The partition table itself is not really part of the operation of the OS itself. So that will not be the issue.

> horribly slow at everything (boot, any action taken after booting, etc.).

The 1st thing to do is

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

This will list the time each segment of the boot process took. If there is something taking a lot of time that can be used for further investigation.

You did not include specifics about your system. Please add those to the question. Brand, make, model are important.